# Automatically update UITableView when Array changes

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a View Controller containing a UITableView that used an NSMutableArray to determine its content via the usual UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods.

In the past I have used NSFetchedResults controller to update the TableView as the result of its query results changing. In this case I would like to update the UITableView appropriately as items are added to/removed from the array.

How should I handle this? Should I wrap the NSMutableArray in a model class with addItem/removeItem methods which use delegation or Notification to trigger reloadData on the UITableView? Or is there a more elegant solution?

There are maximum ~20 items in the array so performance isn't so much of an issue.

Comment: the nsmutableArray is good choice for what you want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that NSArrayController is what I want, however it is not available in iOS, so it looks like KVO is my best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: **Non ARC example**

You could set up the array which your tableview uses as a property

```
//.h

..... {

    NSArray* array_;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* array;

//.m
```

Synthesize the array

```
@synthesize array = array_;
```

We are interested when array changes so override the setter method

```
-(void)setArray:(NSArray*)array {
    if (array_ != array) {
        [array_ release];
        array_ = [array retain];
        [self.tableview reloadData];
    }
 }
```

Then whenever you modify your tableview data, `array:` At the end of modifying the data.

```
self.array = newArray;
```

As it's a property external classes / views will be able to modify array and the table will update.